# Sending two http request one after another

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I have 2 api calls which i want to send one after the other.
I need a response of the 1st one to send the 2nd api request, but i also need the data from first call. Looks like switchMap is the way to go, atm it looks like this:

```
this.apiCall1().pipe(switchMap(res1 => this.apiCall2(res.data))).subscribe(res => ...)
```

but i need to assign the res1.differentData to a variable which seems impossible with switchMap. Or maybe im just missing some syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you to just reemit the value coming from `apiCall1()` and use `forkJoin` to get both values at the end:

```
this.apiCall1().pipe(
  switchMap(res => forkJoin(
    [of(res), this.apiCall2(res)]
  ))).subscribe(console.log)
```

this way you receive an array containing two elements (the results of both calls) at the end.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use map to the inner call to include all or part of the response from outer (usually used in a typical element+details)

```
this.apiCall1().pipe(
  switchMap(res1 => this.apiCall2(res1).pipe(
           map(res2=>({res1:res1,res2:res2})))
  )
```

Comment: This actually seems like the better approach than the one provided by me!

Answer (score 0):

Without running the code myself, here is my take.

Possibly break-out your callback function:

```js
let res1Stored;

this
  .apiCall1()
  .pipe(switchMap(res1 => {
    res1Stored = res1.differentData;
    return this.apiCall2(res.data);
  }))
  .subscribe(res => ...)
```

Hope this helps.